# How to modify and serialize a string in java?

Tags: java

I have a base64 string with field and new value, now conversion is required to be done by adding value at particular field and serializing back to base64 string.

```
String base64ip = BXNyKCRNb25leX3DsipxKQIBSQV2YWx1ZXhw
fieldname = value
value = 20

Output base64op = BXNyKCRNb25leX3DsipxKQIBSQV2YWx1ZXhw with some modification in between due to value.
```

I want to add value 20 to particular fieldname and return the output in serialized base64 format, how to do that?
I tried using writeobject method of serializable class but of no help.

```
    Modify p = new Modify(fieldName, newValue);
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(base64ip);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(p);

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
 String base64op ="";
 base64op=base64ip;
return base64op;
```

Comment: Java serialization is for serializing binary. If you want to write a string as base64 I suggest you use a base64 library.

Comment: e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html